# How to connect WUMC710 to my wireless network as a bridge (WPS fails)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

If y try to connect the linksys WUMC710 AP to my WiFi network as a bridge (to extend the network) with WPS as the instructions says, it fails after the 2 minutes timeout.

If I access the AP through static IP addressing with a cable, I can't see my WiFi SSID in the wireless network list to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the channel of your WiFi network. For me it was at auto (configured to channel 100) and I changed it to fixed channel 44. No it works both with WPS or choosing the WiFi in the AP configuration panel.